# rebase to squash multiple commits on same branch

Tags: git

Can we use rebase to squash multiple commits into one single commit on the same branch?

Taking an example, i have created two topic branches - issueA_1 and issueA_2 from master. I make a couple of commits in both branches, as can be seen in the diagram(i am using commit names here instead of commit hashes for brevity) :

```
           -->  (issueA_1) - commitX1
          /
(master)--
          \
           -->  (issueA_2)
                   |
                commitY1
                   |
                commitY2
```

Then i do :

```
git checkout issueA_2
git rebase -i issueA_1
```

I change the rebase file to :

```
pick commitY1
fixup commitY2
```

After this rebase, the commit history looks like this :

```
           -->  (issueA_1) - commitX1
          /
(master)--
          \
           -->  (issueA_2)
                   |
                commitX1
                   |
                commitY1
                   |
                commitY2
```

I don't need the branch issueA_1 anymore, so i do :

```
git branch -D issueA_1
```

The commit history of issueA_2 isn't pretty enough to be merged into master yet. I want commitX1, commitY1 and commitY2 of this branch to be squashed into 1 single commit before i merge into master. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, the simplest way I find is to do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will let you review the last 3 commits and you can then squash them.

Comment: Using this command I get the following text on my command window -


pick <commit_id_1> <comment_1 written while committing>
pick <commit_id_2> <comment_2 written while committing>

# Rebase 551a895..4a2dc5e onto 551a895 (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
..... and so on.
I'm unable to type any command mentioned on that window.

Comment: @phougatv You probably need to use vim commands. Press `i` to enter interactive mode then change the list of commits as described. Press `esc` to exit interactive mode then press `:x` to exit and save.

Answer (score 3):

In your case,

```
git checkout issueA_2
git rebase -i master
```

or

```
git rebase -i commitX1^ #parent of commitX1 in branch issueA_2
```

should also work. In this case, you don't need to count (I'm usually one off).

Comment: what is `git co`? Did you mean `git checkout` ?

Comment: Would "commitX1^" be identical to "HEAD~3" in this context?

Comment: Yes, if I have counted that correcly ;)

Comment: ok. How could i have missed "git rebase -i master"! That was the simplest and safest option. I guess i was a little nervous thinking of `rebase` and `master` in the same line..it didn't strike me that the command does not effect the master branch at all.