# What to do after git rebase -i HEAD~2

Tags: git

I had 2 commits on the same branch which I wanted to squash into one. Upon googling I came across the following: [rebase to squash multiple commits on same branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323878/rebase-to-squash-multiple-commits-on-same-branch#answer-25323915)

Using the above-mentioned solutions I got the following window:
[image]

Now the problem is I cannot type in anything in this window. **How should I proceed with squashing the commits??**

Comment: Welcome to vim :) You probably want to [configure git to use another editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-editing-commit-messages).

Comment: To get out and abort your rebase, type `<ESC>:cquit<ENTER>`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the link and command. But I am not able to type or paste on that specific window, including the command you just provided. I am able to write at the very bottom of the window, but upon pressing enter (after typing in the command), it keeps adding a new line.

Comment: Hm, weird. Then just close the window, I guess :)

Comment: If you want to move ahead of this window, see - [Vim for Windows - What do I type to save and exit from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708645/vim-for-windows-what-do-i-type-to-save-and-exit-from-a-file#answer-4708659) and [How do I exit Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim#answer-11828573).

Comment: Don't just configure git to use a different editor, configure your environment so all sane tools use your preferred editor.  Add `export EDITOR=your-preferred-editor` to your startup files. (eg `echo export EDITOR=nano >> ~/.bashrc`)

Comment: pressing escape should get you out of insert action and :q will let you exit the rebase command.